# How to vertically align a div with text

Tags: html, web

I've been stuck on this problem for a while. To better explain the question that I'm asking here is a picture: [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuNHU.png)

Hopefully that helps a bit. Here is my code:

```css
.Home {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 35px 60px;
}
```

```html
<p style="text-align: right; background-color: #e9e9e9;font-family:arial;font-size:20px;">upper message</p>

<div style="text-align:center;background-color:black;">
  <img src="/Images/logo-text.png" width="250" hight="240" align="left"> <button class="Home">Home</button>
</div>
```

So what I'm trying to do is have the div align with the text vertically. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The HTML shown contains obsolete attributes (`align`) as well as being a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use devtools to troubleshoot. If you focus on your `<p>` element you'll see that it has 20px margin.

```css
.Home {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 35px 60px;
}
p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<p style="text-align: right; background-color: #e9e9e9;font-family:arial;font-size:20px;">upper message</p>

<div style="text-align:center;background-color:black;">
  <img src="/Images/logo-text.png" width="250" hight="240" align="left"> <button class="Home">Home</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Just 1 simple fix. Thanks again.

Comment: Just a side note, try avoid use inline styles, if all possible, use CSS, might save you headache in the future.

Comment: The HTML shown contains obsolete attributes (`align`) as well as being a typo.